# how to do unit testing for this?

Tags: django, unit-testing, automated-tests, pytest, pytest-django

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username'] #this is my first field to be tested
        password = request.POST['password']  #this is my second field to be tested
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                playlists = Playlist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                return render(request, 'index.html', {'playlists': playlists})
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

## how can i do testing to this code in django and what all i need to install in order to test it

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/

Comment: thanks mate i will refer it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that whole view, you can look into:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/

Basically you can write a test that will send a dummy request with POST method on that view, and then validate by checking the response.

Comment: can you please give me sample code of automation testing. i want to perform for login page .... which has two fields (email and password)  and also  two button(login and cancel)